# How could I find slices' "cpu self time" and "self time" in perfetto UI results like the legacy UI for systrace do?

Tags: cpu, systrace, perfetto

I'm using perfetto to trace my app. I am not using systrace because I need to trace for long duration. However in the perfetto result below, I can only find slices' "wall duration" not the "self duration" and "cpu self duration" which can be found in legacy UI for systrace. I'm sure these two "self" duration's infomation is in the perfetto file, because when I press the "swtich to legacy UI" button, the corresponding legacy UI does show them. However I cannot use the legacy UI directly, for it could only show about 10s trace info of my applications. So how can I find these "self" duration infomation in the perfetto UI, really thanks for any idea.
[perfetto result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUkki.png)
[related legacy ui result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtciZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there - see this [annotated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItE06.png)

All you need to do is go to the "Thread states" tab (annotated 1) in the bottom sheet, and look at the "Running" (annotated 2) "Wall Duration" value (annotated 3).